# Dag generation failure: Invalid Argument

Tags: mining, dag

I have been mining for a while now. I restarted my computer this evening and I have been receiving the error " DAG Generation Failure. Reason: Invalid argument" when running the same bat file I always do. I have not made any changes to my system.

Comment: Which ethereum client are you using?

Comment: I have this issue as well, running it on openclminer(ethminer) 0.9.41

Comment: Having this problem starting today as well

Comment: And which miner? genoil?

Comment: We're going to need more logs to get any further on this. Can someone re-run things using both `--verbosity 5` and `--debug`, then either edit the question to include these logs, or put them somewhere online and send a link?

Comment: An updated solved this issue for me

Comment: Try deleting your dag (`~/.ethash`) and regenerating it.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for some [Reddit users](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/6g53ba/dag_generation_failure_invalid_argument/)

> [–]avazawr... try to use parameter --no-precompute. It helped me
>
> [–]Chadington1... Thanks! It worked for me too.

And this solution worked for someone [on the Ethereum Forum](http://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/13509/dag-generation-failure-reason-invalid-argument)

> Bakoo13 Put the --no-precompute command at the end. If this doesn't
> work anymore (worked for me for 2 days), try the claymore miner. I'm
> trying it out now, too, and it seems to work more stable.