# DAG Generation Failure. Reason: Invalid argument

Tags: go-ethereum

My ethminer was working perfectly fine then my internet went out for a few minutes and this poped up within startup of ethminer DAG Generation Failure. Reason: Invalid argument   i mine on dwarfpool

Comment: This has already been asked: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17546/dag-generation-failure-invalid-argument